# Can vc++ share statics in a a library when using runtime dll loading

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

I'm investigating a plugin type system using Microsoft C++. The problem I have is I'm not able to share a static variable in a shared library between the main program and the plugin library.

Main Program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "..\EngineLib\Engine.h"

typedef void(*PluginFuncPtrType)(void);

int main()
{
    printf("Main Test.\n");

    HINSTANCE hRuntimeDll = LoadLibrary(L"PluginLib.dll");
    if (!hRuntimeDll) {
        printf("Could not load the dynamic library.\n");
    }

    PluginFuncPtrType pluginFuncPtr = (PluginFuncPtrType)GetProcAddress(hRuntimeDll, "PluginFunc");
    if (!pluginFuncPtr) {
        printf("Could not load the function from dynamic library.\n");
    }
    else {
        pluginFuncPtr();
        printf("Main engine counter %i.\n", EngineFunc());
        pluginFuncPtr();
        printf("Main engine counter %i.\n", EngineFunc());
        pluginFuncPtr();
        printf("Main engine counter %i.\n", EngineFunc());
    }

    printf("Press any key to exit...");
    getchar();
}
```

A shared library that is used by the main program (statically linked) and the plugin dll (which also statically links in this shared library)

Shared Library Header (Engine.h):

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
int EngineFunc();
```

Shared Library Implementation:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Engine.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static int _engineCounter = 1;

int EngineFunc()
{
    return _engineCounter++;
}
```

Plugin dll header (Plugin.h):

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "..\EngineLib\Engine.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void PluginFunc(void);
```

Plugin Implementation:

```
#include "Plugin.h"

void PluginFunc(void)
{
    printf("PluginFunc engine counter=%i\n", EngineFunc());
}
```

Output from main.exe:

```
Main Test.
PluginFunc engine counter=1
Main engine counter 1.
PluginFunc engine counter=2
Main engine counter 2.
PluginFunc engine counter=3
Main engine counter 3.
Press any key to exit...
```

**Main.exe** statically links against **EngineLib.lib**.
**PluginLib.dll** statically links against **EngineLib.lib**.

Main does NOT link against PluginLib.dll but instead loads it at runtime.

From what I understand when a dll is loaded at runtime using LoadLibrary it gets it's own virtual memory address space and therefore different static variables to the the same library statically linked into the main program. I believe on Linux dynamically loaded libraries do share the same virtual memory space.

My question is whether there is any approach I can use for Windows to allow the dynamically loaded dll to use the same static variables as the statically linked library?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dll. "EngineStatics.dll". Define the static in this dll, and export it with __declspec(dllexport).

In your exe, add a dependency on the above dll. And declare the same static with __declspec(dllimport).

In your plugin dll, add a dependency on the same dll, and also import it with delcspec(dllimport)

---

This seems far simpler than my original answer of exporting the static from the .exe directly, co-ercing the tools into producing an export lib, and then making the plugin dll link against the EXE's lib file.

Comment: I don't want to access the static _engineCounter variable directly. In my radically simplified example that static variable represents something that both loaded copies of EngineLib update and that two different users of that library need to see each other's updates.